# How to add a list of integers into in a table in sqlite3

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I am writing a database which will be used for a game. So in this database I have a `PLAYERS` table which contains some information regarding the players of the game. For one of the columns of this table, I need to have a list which will contain the integers (IDs) of players which are friend with the current player. (like a friend list)
The problem is that first the size of this list is not defined and will change (by adding or removing a friend) and the second problem is that sqlite3 only lets use the primary values like INT, TEXT, etc. 
So my question is that how I could add such column in my table and modify it accordingly ( meaning that adding or removing contents from it)?
I know by searching that I could add a second table and use it by I don't really know how to that and I would be appreciate it if someone could help and guide me throw it.
Here is some code:

```
  std::string sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYERS("
                    "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    "USERNAME               TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " 
                    "PASSWORD               TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    "SCORE                  REAL NOT NULL  );"; 
  // here I want to add the column that I am talking about with name of FRIENDS which contains the ID (a list of integers) of the other players
  int ret = 0;
  char* errMsg;

  ret = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), nullptr, 0, &errMsg);
  if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Table creation error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << std::endl;
    sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    return false;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Table created successfully." << std::endl;
  }

  std::ostringstream osql;
  osql << "INSERT INTO PLAYERS (USERNAME, PASSWORD, SCORE) VALUES('" << "mra" << "', '" << "12456" << "', " << 20.2 << ");";
  std::string sql = osql.str();

  int ret = 0;
  char* errMsg;

  ret = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), nullptr, 0, &errMsg);
  if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Insertion error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << std::endl;
    sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    return false;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Insertion was successfull." << std::endl;
  }
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship between Players. A *junction table* better serves this purpose than a column of a list of friends.

The junction table can have a structure like this:

```
| Player1 | Player2 |
| 1       | 2       |
| 1       | 3       |
```

With a CHECK constraint you can enforce Player1 < Player2 so that you eliminate the possibility of duplicate friendship relationships.

The sql to create such a table (`FRIENDS`) will be:

```
CREATE TABLE "FRIENDS" (
    "PLAYER1"   INTEGER,
    "PLAYER2"   INTEGER,
    CHECK(PLAYER1<PLAYER2),
    FOREIGN KEY("PLAYER1") REFERENCES "PLAYERS"("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY("PLAYER1","PLAYER2"),
    FOREIGN KEY("PLAYER2") REFERENCES "PLAYERS"("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE` ensures that when a primary key in the `PLAYERS` table related rows in the `FRIENDS` table are deleted too.

So you just have to query the `FRIENDS` table to get a player's friends.

Comment: Did you intend `CHECK(PLAYER1 <> PLAYER2)`?

Comment: @DavidVasconcelos No, I did intend on `PLAYER1 < PLAYER2` so that there is only 1 variant of a pairing: 1,3 but not 3,1 for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I also know how to add or delete some data in this table? For example what do I have to do if I wanted to make ID 1 and ID 2 friends?

Comment: Also I would like to know how I could search in this table? Thank you so much

Comment: @Mohammadreza To insert just do `INSERT INTO FRIENDS (PLAYER1, PLAYER2) VALUES(2,3);` Make sure Player1 < Player2.

Comment: @Mohammadreza To get all the friends for a particular persion (e.g. id=2) you can do a select union: `select PLAYER1 from FRIENDS where PLAYER2=2 union select PLAYER2 from FRIENDS where PLAYER1 = 2;`

Comment: @jignatius but my problem is that the select union gives me the id of each friend. i want to get username of the friend. So how can I get the username from the id obtained by the code that you gave in your reply? Thank you again for your response

Comment: @Mohammadreza Then extend the select to get username using the ids: `select USERNAME from PLAYERS where id in
(select PLAYER1 from FRIENDS where PLAYER2=2 union select PLAYER2 from FRIENDS where PLAYER1 = 2);`